# angularjs : how to get the same picture when using self definied directive 'fileModel'?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

We know in angularjs there is no official directive to manipulate input file. The common method is to define a directive to get the file, codes as below:

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('fileModel',  function($parse){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                })
                scope.file = (event.srcElement || event.target).files[0];
                scope.getFile(scope.file);
            })
        }
    }
})
```

the html codes are as beblow:

```
<input id="file-upload" type="file" file-model="myFile" name="defectImage" accept="image/*" />
```

I am using the above directive to input image. However there is one defect in above codes. That is when I select a same image multiple times, I will only get the file on the first time. So how to modify the above codes to realize selecting a same image multiple times and each time I can get the file ?

Comment: can you add your html part too, the directive you use

Comment: Are you restricted to use directive or not?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are selecting the same file again and again, the `"change" event` is not fired(*since the file is not changed!!*). You may need to clear the selected file(`scope.file=null`) every-time the user clicks to upload a file. Hope it helps. :)